# Why is the exponential of sets the function set?

Tags: category-theory

I have asked a question about exponentials yesterday, but there is something that is not clear to me so I thought I should ask a different question.

By looking at the case of sets, I am not sure about the following: If we suppose we have no idea of what the exponential of two sets $B$ and $C$ is, how does one identify it with $\text{Hom}(B,C)$? Why is the set $S$, endowed with a function $g:S\times B\to C$, such that for any set $A$ and function $f:A\times B\to C$ the property of the exponential holds (existence of a unique function that makes the triangle commute), the set $\text{Hom}(B,C)$ of functions from $B$ to $C$? When you know it, it is easy to show that it does indeed satisfy the definition, but if you don't?

Comment: Take the case $A = 1$.

Comment: Hi! I noticed that you've asked three questions by now, none of which have an accepted answer. If this is because you were unaware of this functionality (since you're new to math.SE), I would like to inform you that when you take a satisfying (for you) answer, you can accept it. In order to see how to do this, take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see basic functinalities.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the exponentiation of a set $S$, if it exists, is the right adjoint of the functor 
$ - \times S \colon \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}, $
i.e. a functor $F_S \colon \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ such that there is a bijection
$$ \hom(A\times S, B) \simeq \hom(A,F_S(B)) $$
natural in the sets $A,B$.

As **Zhen Lin** pointed it out in the comments, take $A$ a singleton : one must have
$$ \hom(\{\ast\} \times S, B) \simeq \hom(\{\ast\},F_S(B)), $$
which says that $F_S(B)$ (which is isomorphic to set on the right) must be isomorphic to $\hom (S, B)$ (which is isomorphic to the set on the left). So one try $F_S(-) := (-)^S$ and check that it indeed is a right adjoint to $- \times S$ (which is not hard, as you said).